# Microsoft SQL Server Management Stdio prevent disconnected tab lost its query execution time & row returned

Tags: ssms

I noticed that when
[Query Executed Successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8TGm.png) there are execution time & number of rows shown in bottom "status bar" in each query tab. However, when the tab become idle for sometime, it would disconnected and lost such information. I would like to troubleshoot the execution time of some complex queries overnight, so I didn't want that happened. I am unable to locate any settings to keep these information in query options or options.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, there are [Include client Statistics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtYCJ.png) for such purpose, the "total execution time" is what I needed.